# How to run munin-node on SmartOS Global Zone?

Tags: munin, smartos

I'd like to run `munin-node` on my SmartOS Global Zone, to remotely monitor hardware and software status.

I've tried `pkgin in munin-node-1.4.5`, but installation fails because it can't create the `munin` user account (which makes sense since `/etc/passwd` is part of the root ramdisk).

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by installing from source.  Here's the recipe I used:

```
pkgin in gmake perl
cpan HTML::Template Log::Log4perl Net::Server Net::Server::Fork
mkdir -p /opt/local/src
cd /opt/local/src
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/munin/files/stable/2.0.9/munin-2.0.9.tar.gz/download
tar zxvf munin-2.0.9.tar.gz
cd munin-2.0.9
vi Makefile.config
    # change PREFIX to `/opt/local`
    # change CONFDIR to `/opt/local/etc/munin`
    # change LIBDIR to `$(PREFIX)/lib/munin`
    # change STATEDIR to `$(DESTDIR)/var/run`
    # change USER and GROUP to `nobody`
make
make install-common-prime install-node-prime install-plugins-prime
vi /opt/local/etc/munin/munin-node.conf
    # set access controls
munin-node-configure --shell | sh -x
mkdir -p /opt/custom/smf
```

And create `/opt/custom/smf/munin-node.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE service_bundle SYSTEM '/usr/share/lib/xml/dtd/service_bundle.dtd.1'>
<service_bundle type='manifest' name='export'>
  <service name='network/munin-node' type='service' version='0'>
    <create_default_instance enabled='true'/>
    <single_instance/>
    <exec_method name='start' type='method' exec='/opt/local/sbin/munin-node' timeout_seconds='0'>
      <method_context/>
    </exec_method>
    <exec_method name='stop' type='method' exec=':kill' timeout_seconds='0'>
      <method_context/>
    </exec_method>
  </service>
</service_bundle>
```